# Is it possible to update BOSS linux from version 3 to version 8?

Tags: upgrade

I am user of Windows trying to use Linux. I have BOSS Linux installed long time ago along with Windows which I didn't used it for long time but now I like to make a switch to Linux but in order to use latest version of BOSS Linux  (version 8) and so I need to upgrade it (mine is version 3) Is it possible to update ? and how to update it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to update ?

No, sorry.

It's unlikely enough that you could update *any* Linux distro over a jump of so many versions flawlessly. In case of BOSS 3 to BOSS 8, it's pretty much impossible:

BOSS 3 is from from 2008, and only available in a 32 bit version. BOSS 8 is 64 bit only. So, not only would you update, you would also have to switch architectures. As far as I'm aware, that's unsupported. (You need a 64-bit PC for BOSS 8 to run at all. If your PC is from 2008 or before, there's a realistic chance you don't have a 64-bit PC.)

BOSS itself doesn't offer any of the older versions to download, so you also can't make a few "small" updates instead of one big one.

**It should be much, much less work to just make a new installation, even if an expert figured out how to do an update across so many versions.**

Also, BOSS 8 is already pretty old. BOSS, I honestly think, is a dead end. Unless you're forced to use it, I'd just go with [Linux Mint 20.3 "Cinnamon Edition"](https://linuxmint.com/), which uses the same desktop environment as BOSS 8, is based on the same Debian base system, but much more actively maintained and developed. **Only use BOSS if your Indian government job forces you to. If it does, you probably have an administrator that should set up the system for you.**

Comment: OK, The exact version I use is 3.14. something which I use on a 64 bit laptop. Mainly I want use and learn ROS so I thought to update BOSS and use ROS with Ubuntu on a VM on BOSS Linux.

Comment: ROS=Robot operating system? Because that has nothing to do with BOSS and can be better used on pretty much any other modern Linux! And if you can use VMs, you can use them directly on your windows as well - no need to boot BOSS to start a VM.

Comment: Yes it is Robot Operating System. I have storage issues in Windows that's why I try to use BOSS as it has free space and so if I can't use this BOSS then It would be a waste and occupying useless storage of disk.

Comment: this makes no sense. You could just as well remove the BOSS partition and use the memory for windows, or for a VM on windows.

Comment: Oh Ok Then I will try that